# Get Xpath (or element) when page has randomly generated ID's HTML Unit

Tags: java, htmlunit

so I am using HTML Unit to click an item on a webpage. I usually use Xpath to select my items, but this page gives every element a randomly generated ID and class. I usually use Google Chrome to get the Xpath of elements, but it gives me something like this: `//*[@id=":og"]` where :og is the randomly generated ID. I know that sometimes chrome gives me Xpath without any ID's or Classes, like this: `/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/input[2]` Is it possable to get an Xpath that does not rely on IDs or Classes in a case like this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to construct shorter xpaths or alternative ones based on tags only you can use plugins that will let you do just that.  Particularly I favor the Selenium IDE in firefox, but in Chrome you can use things like Xpath Helper.  There are others you can explore by searching the chrome web store.